# How to detect if Vim is running in restricted mode?

Tags: vim

... or in any mode for that matter.

I just want to prevent some extensions from loading when that is the case, something like:

```
if ! currentmode('restricted')
     Bundle('some-extension')
endif
```

Answer (score 5):

You're right; a special variable like `v:vimmode` would be helpful, but I don't think such a thing currently exists. Why not raise this on the [vim_dev mailing list](http://www.vim.org/community.php)?!

In the meantime, you have to detect the mode through the result of invoking something that is forbidden in restricted mode. My best idea that is the least intrusive on success is invoking `writefile()` with an empty file name:

```
silent! call writefile([], '')
" In restricted mode, this fails with E145: Shell commands not allowed in rvim
" In non-restricted mode, this fails with E482: Can't create file <empty>
let isRestricted = (v:errmsg =~# '^E145:')
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this is a good idea:

`restricted-mode` disabled external commands (also some related functions). If we call external command or some certain functions in a rvim, we get Error `E145`.

So maybe you could just  call some dummy external command via `system()`, then catch the Exception `E145`. to distinguish if it is in restricted mode. e.g.

```
try
    call system("echo x") "or even call system("")
catch /E145/
"your codes
endtry
```

hope it helps